# How to convert string to object to use as key in $filter in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

in below code,

```
var searchColumn = $scope.employeeSearch;
//searchColumn = "Name"
```

Result of searchColumn is "Name", which is a string and i am passing it as key to filter as below

```
$scope.ResultSrc = $filter('filter')(tempsearch, { searchColumn: $scope.filterText });
```

Here search fails because searchColumn = "Name" which is a string. I want it as object searchColumn = Name without quotes

How to convert string to object?

Comment: what are trying to achieve? create a demo of the issue you are facing.

Comment: I dont think giving Name without quotes will help. Illustrate your problem.

Comment: i want to pass key value for filter dynamically. Here key value is searchColumn, which i get as string. Instead of searchColumn = "Name"
i want searchColumn = Name, so i want to convert.

Comment: yes it works yash, if i hardcode column value as  $scope.ResultSrc = $filter('filter')(tempsearch, { Name: $scope.filterText }); it is working fine, but if i get it dynamically whn i debug it shows as $scope.ResultSrc = $filter('filter')(tempsearch, { "Name": $scope.filterText }); . So i want to convert searchColumn before passing it to filter